# Can you figure out how to solve this chinese Primary School exercise on sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

A little cousin is stuck on a math problem. I tried to solve it for him without success ... As it's somehow graphical, I provide a screenshot.

[image]

The top circles look like a Fibonacci sequence starting at 2, but it doesn't match with the 36. Numbers in the bottom line makes even less sense to me. It all feels like too much information has been removed for this problem to be easily solved...

Comment: Is it allowed to use numbers like $\frac32$?

Comment: Only natural numbers are allowed unfortunately :/

Comment: @fifou What I was thinking was $2 \cdot 4$ (top-left circle and bottom-left circle) + $2 \cdot 4$ (top-right circle and bottom-right circle) = $16$.

Answer (score 1):

These problems have usually many solutions. Here is one with the rule:

[image]

I bet that this is not the solution the teacher expects. But this "solution" works.

Comment: $$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rrr}
\enclose{circle}{a}&  &\enclose{circle}{b} \\
&\enclose{box}{ab+cd}&                     \\
\enclose{circle}{c}&  &\enclose{circle}{d} 
\end{array}
$$
Provides a [more readable and SEO-friendly output](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11696/290189).

Comment: That's not a correct answer, as in the first case, you would have 2x2 + 4x4 = 16

Comment: @fifou: I'll correct in a second.

Comment: @fifu: I've corrected, sorry.